# Using Vim Diff To Create A Patch File?

Tags: external-command, vimdiff

I'm currently using vim 7.3 on Windows 7.

The first question I have is it even possible to create the patch file from within vim itself? I understand the basic idea, but anytime I attempt to run

```
diff -u file.txt file_new.txt > file.patch
```

I get a `E488: Trailing characters` error. However, using the Windows command prompt to run `diff.exe` from the vim folder seems to work just fine. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

Second - and I'm sure there's an explanation in the manual but `:help diff` didn't seem to show anything - what's the difference between `diff -u` and `diff -c`? From what I saw online, both `-u` and `-c` were both used to create a patch file. When I tested it myself using the command prompt, they both appeared to generate identical files.

[Edit] I realized I must have done something wrong as I just checked again and the files generated by `diff -u` and `diff -c` are different. Still curious what the differences are and when I should use one or the other.

Comment: How did you run that command? `:!diff -u file.txt file_new.txt > file.patch` or `diff -u file.txt file_new.txt > file.patch`?  It seems to me you're trying to run an external command directly in Vim.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do because I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:!<cmd>` is how we usually run external commands from within Vim. See [`:he :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3A%21). `:diff` presumably calls Vim's `:diffget` command, but definitely not the external `diff` program as you intended it.

`:help diff` won't say anything about difference between `diff -u` and `diff -c`, because those are options for the external `diff` program, and nothing to do with Vim. Assuming you're using GNU `diff` (POSIX `diff` doesn't specify `-u`), `-u` produces  *unified* diffs, and `-c` produces a *context* diff with, 3 lines of context. See the [GNU `diff` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Context-Format) for more information.

---

It seems you must be using GNU `diff`, since the GNU docs say about unified diffs:

> At present, only GNU diff can produce this format and only GNU patch can automatically apply diffs in this format.

Comment: _At present, only GNU diff can produce this format and only GNU patch can automatically apply diffs in this format._ - For suitable values of _present_. :) OpenBSD's `diff` and `patch` have supported unified patches since June 2003.

Comment: @lcd047 somebody needs to submit a patch for the GNU documentation.

Comment: Make sure it's a upatch!